# Regex expression to extract From & To Date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, web-scraping, list-comprehension

I am trying to extract from and to year in separate group using regex but not able to extract because of different format as shown below.
Applied Regex : **`([0-9]+)-?([0-9a-z]+)`**

Below is the complete data that need to be extracted:

```
['165-180 A.D.',
 '1520-unknown',
 '1665',
 '1817-1923',
 'Late 1800s',
 '1918-1920',
 '1957-1958',
 '2009']
```

The above regex extracts 165,1520,**166** in group 1 and 2019,unknown,**5** in group 2. Need to put 1665 in group1 and blank field in group2 regex.
Similarly Late 1800s in group1

````
wp_page = requests.get("https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/2020/local/retropolis/coronavirus-deadliest-pandemics/")
wp_soup = bs(wp_page.content, 'html.parser')

[names.get_text() for  names in wp_soup.find_all('h5')][0:-2]

wp_year_from_list=[]
wp_year_to_list=[]
wp_year_regex=re.compile('([0-9]+)-?([0-9a-z]+)')
for names in wp_soup.find_all('h5'):
    if (wp_year_regex.search(names.text)!= None):
        wp_year_from_list.append(wp_year_regex.search(names.text).group(1))
        wp_year_to_list.append(wp_year_regex.search(names.text).group(2))```
````

Comment: Could you please include your code and results so that others can reproduce your problem? Thank you!

Comment: @mozart_kv467 updated post with code

Comment: thanks @Mandy8055, that is what i needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement you need to add `?` quantifier for your second group. So your regex will look like:

```
([0-9]+)-?([0-9a-z]+)?
                     ^^
```

**Explanation of the above regex**:

> **`([0-9]+)`** - Capturing group which captures digits 1 or more time.
>
> **`-?`** - Matches a hyphen literally zero or 1 time.
>
> **`([0-9a-z]+)?`** - Second capturing group capturing digits and letters 1 or more times and the group can appear 0 or 1 time.

[image]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [here.](https://regex101.com/r/kB6sun/1/)

Answer (score 0):

using `*` in the second group to get your required result.

```
([0-9]+)-?([0-9a-z]+)*
                     ^^
```

Comment: This is also a way to get the result expected by OP.+1